# How to get first n elements from Hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash and i have sorted it using the values

```
@friends_comment_count.sort_by{|k,v| -v}
```

Now i only want to get hash of top five elements .. One way is to use a counter and break when its 5. 
 What is preferred way to do in ruby ?

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
h = { 'a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 }

# get the first two
p Hash[*h.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..1].flatten]
```

**EDITED**:

```
# get the first two (more concisely)
p Hash[h.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..1]]
```

Comment: You don't need the splat or `flatten`, just feed the AoA to `Hash[]`: `Hash[h.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..1]]`

Comment: I like this syntax more: `p h.sort_by { |k,v| -v }[0..1].to_h`

Answer (score 29):

You do this:

```
h = {"test"=>"1", "test2"=>"2", "test3"=>"3"}
```

Then, if you wanted the first 2:

```
p h.first(2).to_h
```

Result:

```
=> {"test"=>"1", "test2"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Not the most efficient way to go about it, particularly with large hashes, but a nice, simple hack when you need it.

Comment: In what way is it not efficient? because the hash has to be reconstructed again? i think all the other solutions have similar work that needs to be done.

Answer (score 7):

New to ruby myself (please be nice if I'm wrong guys!) but does this work?

```
@friends_comment_count.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.first 5
```

Works for me in IRB, if I've understood what you're trying to achieve correctly

Comment: That will work, but the result is an array of arrays. `[[:a,1],[:b,2]]`. The hash is converted to an array and then the `first` method is used on that array

Comment: But you can turn that array of arrays back into a Hash by wrapping it in `Hash[]` thusly: `Hash[@friends_comment_count.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.first 5]`.

Comment: Thanks guys, almost scared to answer questions after the hazing i got yesterday!

Answer (score 4):

You can't sort a Hash and that's why `sort_by` does NOT sort your Hash. It returns a sorted Array of Arrays.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 2.2.0 and later, [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) takes an optional integer argument that makes it return an array instead of just one element.  This means you can do:

```
h = { 'a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 }
n = 2
p h.max_by(n, &:last).to_h   # => {"b"=>20, "c"=>30}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are not ordered by nature (even thought in Ruby implementation they are). Try geting converting your Hash to Array and get [0,4] out of it

Comment: are you sure they are in Ruby? `sort_by` returns an array

Comment: Hashes are ordered as of Ruby 1.9, but in 1.8 they were not.

Comment: @Oleg (Can't type your name on a lot of devices, yanno) Yes, they're ordered by insertion order as of 1.9.

Comment: that is strange... like lots of other things in Ruby